# Reset css for a specific div

Tags: css, widget, reset

I´m using Twitter Bootstrap as a framework for my project.
I also have a div#widget with name and email form fields and a submit button
i want to reset to defaults all the css only for that div and use my custom classes.
i tried with:

```
div#widget * {
   background-color: #FFF;
   font-size: 12px;
   ...
}
```

the problem with that code is that i need to specify every css property

I´m looking for a magical solution like

```
div#widget * {
   // reset to factory defaults here
}
```

Comment: no such thing tmk... And note that input fields do not inherit styling from there parent (like font-size), unlike most other html elements.You will have to reset them all, one by one I'm afraid...

Comment: I don't know if you can do that, but you can try to simulate the default css format of an HTML document with this reference:
[Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can work it the other way round.

With :not() selector.

```
div:not(#widget) element { 
   /*Rules here will apply to each element wich are not inside div#widget */
}
```

Comment: (2013. note:) still not xBrowser compatible.

Comment: I need to do exactly the opposite :)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3 using selectivizir , makes this selector usable. @handsome: I'm trying to tell you to do the oppposite way you are doing. This opposite way of yours , no need to reset anything, cause you won't declare anything for #widget childs in the first place. Isn't it a more efficient way to do ?:not(#widget) exclude #widget from getting style => no style ? => no reset to do !

Comment: The problem with this is: if I give you the link of my widget you will be able to add it to your page and also modify it with css!

Comment: hi, not my intention :) . you can filter http request to avoid this. You have information, what you do with it yours :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid The only way to do it is to study an element *defaults* and to painfully reset the needed styles.

Comment: or update selectors with :not() pseudo-selector to exclude one from the rules